# Appium test non-launcher activities

Tags: android, junit, appium

I attempted to run a JUnit test using Appium as below. The script runs fine if I set `capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".MainActivity");`. However, when I try to launch a child activity instead (as the script below), it says that activity has never been launched. I have been using Robotium and it supports testing child activities without having to go through launcher activity; I hope I can do the same on Appium.

```
package com.test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class ShowdownTest {

    AppiumDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "Application");
        File app = new File(appDir, "app-debug-unaligned.apk");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus 5");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.sample.app");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", ".ChildActivity1");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        //fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command `aapt dump badging yourapk.apk` it shows the original activity names of all launch able activities. Make sure that it matches the one you are putting in desired capabilities. This should solve your problem.